# HaverstHQ Chosen Picker Missing Down Arrow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-chosen

I we use HaverstHQ Chosen Picker for our app and all of a sudden the down arrow on the drop down box has disappeared. See this pic: [Picture of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COouq.jpg)

Any help appreciated!

EDIT:

So the app is a rails app, hosted on heroku, postgres backend and backbone front. We are using the plugin from HarvestHQ "Chosen", but the inverted arrow has disappeared from the right hand side of the drop down box. The drop down box still works. See picture for the best explanation.

Comment: Please add some more details about your app and the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. My problem was the location of the chosen-sprite.png file.  The png is referenced in the chosen.css file and the reference is relative to the location of that file.  I moved the file to the same directory as chosen.css and the icons reappeared.